# ¿Cómo imprimir los elementos de una matriz y de dos vectores en forma de una tabla? printf C++

Tags: c++, array, matrices, tablas, ordenar

Tengo **dos vectores de tipo string** con elementos predeterminados y **una matriz de tipo entero** que se llena con números aleatorios:

```
string vector1[5] = {"columna 1", "columna 2", "columna 3", "columna 4", "columna 5"};
string vector2[5] = {"fila 1", "fila 2", "fila 3", "fila 4", "fila 5"};
int matriz[5][5];

srand(time(NULL));

for( int i=0; i<5 ; i++)
{
    for( int j=0; j<5; j++)
    {
      matriz[i][j]=1+rand()%(1000-1);
      cout<<matriz[i][j]<<"   ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Al momento de ejecutarlo me da algo parecido a esto, pero se ve muy desordenado debido a que los números son aleatorios no se puede predecir un orden.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría poder centrar los elementos de la matriz pero con un orden respecto a los elementos de mis vectores, ¿hay alguna forma de hacerlo con la funcion printf? Creo que sería algo como printf("%8d%13d... pero se me hace muy confuso entender esa sintaxis con arreglos y peor aun con matrices. Mi idea es como se muestra en la siguiente tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tendras que calcular el espacio que ocupan los numeros, y luego meter el padding que sea necesario

Comment: Podrías usar manipuladores definidos en el header iomanip de la librería estándar de c++. Podrías mirar left, right y setw. Aunque no hay forma en sí de centrarlos, lo puedes alinear. Otra opción es revisar la librería Boost, que te da más opciones a la hora de formatear la salida.

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios! Tendré que ir probrando

Comment: @JhonRayo99 Disculpa tal vez sabes como hacerlo con la función printf?

Comment: hola, he notado que llevas repitiendo este error en anteriores publicaciones.Por favor lee https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask y muestranos el output tal cual es no con fotos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ¿hay alguna forma de hacerlo con la función `printf`?

La hay. Pero `printf` es una herramienta de las cabeceras de [c](/questions/tagged/c), dado que tu código es [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) y lo has etiquetado como tal, usaremos C++:

```
for( int i=0; i<5 ; i++)
{
    for( int j=0; j<5; j++)
    {
      matriz[i][j]=1+rand()%(1000-1);
      cout<<setw(5)<<matriz[i][j]<<"   ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Mediante [`std::setw`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) manipulas el ancho (`w`idth) de la salida, yo he usado un ancho de cinco, tú usa el ancho que quieras, ese código muestra la siguiente salida:

> ```
> 356     484     892     287     989   
> 316     177     450     237     926   
> 800     827     430     882     967   
> 485     640     981     565      50   
> 314     441      53     526     497
> ```

Para imprimir las etiquetas de fila y columna, tan sólo debes añadirlas al bucle:

```
// Titulos de columna
cout << setw(9) << ' ';
for (const auto &titulo : titulo_columna)
    cout << setw(9) << titulo << ' ';
cout << '\n';

for (int fila = 0; fila != 5; ++fila)
{
    // Titulos de fila
    cout << setw(9) << titulo_fila[fila];
    // Valores
    for (auto &valor : matriz[fila])
    {
        valor = 1 + rand() % (1000 - 1);
        cout << setw(9) << valor << ' ';
    }
    cout << '\n';
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVFdS8MwFH1ufsV1om2ZY@0@HrTrfsHwSX1RkZBmI9AmpUkVHPvt9SappcwhlHDOzc2559yyup6xkspD110Lycq24LARSpuG02pLxrWKSlGPS9gk5GFLiJAGKipkFJMjCVqNVZC04rqmjIM2RUYC3wxGmLZUH0yVbSXp6/odcjhOegrp5A4GshiT5ZisxmQ9Of2R34ty0LbYCzu0GNByQKsBeTGfBxW/UQS/jOCAhsoiMqLi0ePzbhfHtjifw5ObqAEX0jsiAVOtgc0GNDdf0X1sYQghCu9VAxFTUhugrVFw6/3Cw9leYhJcEum7B7nflvBNhtaOk7fmXZYcksyjqxzWGUynlqA0/qMz5/biv5F@ofbAXbjHL7RUDddI3FCf5tMWMUy/O9dvo9iBgb/MIYUpuF3GcANRmiQJzCCNre4lA/7ZEDk4jXz63FgiQcNN20hMTE5d9wM)</kbd>.

Comment: Gracias! Me sirvió! Y disculpa como puedo hacer para poder el vector al lado izquierdo de la matriz? Porque poner el vector encima de la matriz y que coincida con las columnas es facil, pero no logro poner el vector antes y a la derecha la matriz

Comment: Tendrás que escribir el comentario de otra manera, porque no entiendo lo que estás preguntando.

Comment: Ok, lo redactaré de otra manera. Como se puede ver en el código que yo subí en esta pregunta tengo dos vectores de tipo string (vector 1: columnas y vector 2: filas), como quisiera imprimir lo más parecido a una tabla tendría que imprimir el vector de las columnas horizontalmente, y el vector de las filas verticalmente, eso ya se como hacerlo. Mi conflicto es cuando quiero imprimir la matriz entre esos dos vectores. Gracias a tu comentario anterior ya pude que los datos siempre estén ordenados, pero ahora como logro ubicar primero el vector de las filas y justo a la derecha la matriz?